# Transform python requests's exceptions to django-rest-framework's API exceptions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm developing a REST API using django-rest-framework that needs to interact with a 3rd party API.
I use [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) for comunication with this 3rd party API.
Some recurrent pattern I get in my code is making a request from an `APIView` handler

```py
def calculate_order(order):

        url = f"https://api.anotherservice.com/orders/calculate/"

        try:
            response = requests.post(url, json=order.data)
            response.raise_for_status()
            # TODO: handle errors, just printing and re-raising for now
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            raise errh
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print(errc)
            raise errc
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print(errt)
            raise errt
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print(err)
            raise err

        return response.json()

# ... In my view

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # ... Some preprocessing code here

        order_calculated = calculate_order(order)

        return Response(order_calculated, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

DRF implements a mechanism that hanldes

> - Subclasses of `APIException` raised inside REST framework.
> - Django's `Http404` exception.
> - Django's `PermissionDenied` exception.

I was wondering if there's a package for transforming requests's exceptions to exceptions objects that DRF can handle.
Also I'll be glad to know any recomendation on how this should be implemented (best practices).

I was googling it but terms with "Django" and "requests" drop results mostly of Django itself.